# What is the difference between the manifolds $ S^{1} {×} ̃ S^{2} $ (skew product) and $S^{1}×S^{2}$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

What is the difference between the manifolds $ S^{1} {×} ̃ S^{2} $ (skew product) and $S^{1}×S^{2}$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $S^1\tilde{\times} S^2$?  This is a non-trivial $S^2$ bundle over $S^1$?

Comment: No. It's twisted or skew product of $S^{1}$ over  $S^{2}$.

Comment: Can you include the definition of it?

Comment: My problem is that I can't find any definition or information on that.

Comment: Well, where did you see the notation or the terminology?

Comment: I'm learning Heegaard diagrams of  nonorientable manifolds. If you google twisted product you can find these two manifolds but I need to know more about their difference.

Comment: Well, all the $S^1$ bundles over $S^2$ have orientable total spaces, so I really do think you mean a non-trivial $S^2$ bundle over $S^1$ (which is non-orientable).  There is a unique such object, and you can think about it as the quotient of $S^2\times S^1$ by the diagonal antipodal action.  That is, $S^1\tilde{\times} S^2$ is $S^1\times S^2/\sim$ where $(x,y)\sim (-x,-y)$.  It has the same fundamental group as $S^1\times S^2$, and $H^\ast$ of it is $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, 0 , $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in degrees 0,1,2,3.  I am not a 3-manifold topologist; I know nothing of Heegaard diagrams.

Comment: Which book do you kindly recommend?

Comment: For general bundles stuff, I like Steenrod's "The topology of fiber bundles".  In terms of classifying bundles over spheres, the key term is "clutching functions".  I am also using the fact that $Diff^+(S^k)$ deformation retracts to $SO(k+1)$ for small values of $k$.  For $k=2$, this is due to Smale.  For large $k$, it's generally false.  For the topology of these bundles, you should be able to prove everything I said using Steenrod's book.  I happen to be using these non-trivial bundles in a paper I'm currently writing, so knew the values off the top of my head.

Comment: Very instructive!